# Nginx multiple directories with static references

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx server on which I want to host two seperate react apps, let's call them Aapp and Bapp.

The folder structure is like this

- Aapp (directory)

  - index.html
  - script.js
  - style.css
- Bapp (directory)

  - index.html
  - script.js
  - style.css
- ..other files and directories

I then have my config file setup like this:

```
server {
  root home/user/Aapp;
  index index.html;
      
  location ^~ /Bapp {
    allow all;
    alias /home/user/Bapp;
  }
  ....
}
```

Visiting the url my-domain/Bapp is successfully showing index.html from the folder 'Bapp' but it is including the script.js and style.csss from 'Aapp' instead of the ones from 'Bapp'.

Is there a way to tell the server if the file request is coming from the Bapp folder, it should use the 'Bapp' folder files? or do I need to update it in my application build script? (not ideal as different environments may differ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle setting the base URL for the application in application setting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134785/how-to-set-a-base-url-for-react-router-at-the-app-level

Handling this issue cannot be done in a good way with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might be more script-based than server based.  In your react apps, do you reference the files as src="/script.js" or just src="./script.js"?

What I imagine the issue is here is that your scripts are referencing the absolute home which is /home/user/Aapp instead of referencing the relative location.

Comment: The reference is like src="/script.js"

Comment: Yeah that’s the problem. That is referencing the other app’s script. Reference it as “./script.js”.